# Disable WER while application is running

Tags: c++, windows-error-reporting

I am working on an application that continuously opens IE, performs a task, closes it and then repeats.  However in the event that IE crashes during execution the system is prepared to continue onto the next iteration however the error report remains open and does not allow the process to fully close.  This means that it continues to occupy memory until a user clicks the dialog box saying to ignore the error.

Currently there are two solutions that I am looking at, the use of VectoredExceptionHandlers, and the ability to completely disable WER.

My understanding of VectoredExceptionHandlers is that they will intercept any exception thrown by my application and deal with them before they make it to WER.  However since the crash is actually occurring in the IE process that my application started I am not sure if these handlers would still be able to prevent WER from receiving the exception.

I also do not wish to disable WER completely on the system as the other questions on StackOverflow suggest, I only want it disabled while my application is running.

Does anyone have any more knowledge into these options or a better way to handle this?

Comment: I would like to point out that WER is not the only WER-like hassle to disable. There are several other dialog-out-of-nowhere shooting mechanism on windows. It would be great if this questoin can develop in a comprehensive reference to disable them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WER Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page from MSDN might be what you want to take a look at at. There's a section in the registry for excluded applications. And there seems to be this [WerAddExcludedApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function you can call. Judging by the page on [Vectored Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it's probably not going to help you catching exceptions from a different application.

Comment: I was under the impression that Vectored Exception Handling wouldn't work, so I am glad you can at least confirm that piece.  Going to take a look at WerAddExcludedApplication and see if that works.

Comment: @EEP Keep in mind that all this function is doing is probably just writing the registry. You may need to restart your computer to see the effect. In which case, it would be a little suckful.